# Are all layout elements that are available on Android Phones available on Android Wear?

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

Android Wear Watches are a lot smaller then Android phones, but when looking over the Android API pages and training guides, I didn't see any restrictions on layout elements. Some layouts, however, wouldn't make sense on some watches. For example, a large custom layout ListView wouldn't fit very well on round watches. Are all layout elements really available on Android Wear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all layouts are available (`WebView` for example). You can see the unsupported libraries [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html).

And [some layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#UiLibrary) are meant to be used in Android Wear only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction as far as I know. There are some adjustments that one need to pay attention to in order to have a pleasant UI on both square and round displays, by adjusting the location of items and taking advantage of what the platform adds for handling round vs square, etc but outside of that, all the layouts are, as far as I know, available there too.